# Android compiling error with Phonegap. Something like Gradle Android build tool

Tags: cordova, gradle, compilation

After several months I am trying to update my Android app with Phonegap.
PG version I am using:

```
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.1.1" />
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
```

Phonegap build raise this error when compiling proccess:

```
Error - One of your plugins required the gradle android build tool to build - 

Build Date: 2016-05-26 08:57:24 +0000
/project/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
                ^

Error: Project contains at least one plugin that requires a system library.      
This is not supported with ANT. Please build using gradle.
    at /project/cordova/lib/build.js:169:27
    at _fulfilled (/project/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done   (/project/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/project/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /project/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/project/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:417:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:346:13)
```

Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Change the build tool to gradle. [PhoneGap Preference](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_preferences.md.html#Preferences)

```
<preference name="android-build-tool" value="ant|gradle" />
```

Same issue [here in PhoneGap Community](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/phonegap-build-android-build-failing-error-one-of-your-plugins-required-the-gradle-android-build-tool-to-build?rfm=1)